# How do I get the existing value of the fields in a django form when going back in the browser?

Tags: django

I'm trying to understand how django populates the data in a form when I go back in a browser

In the debugger when I go back in the browser it generates a GET request, not a POST and so the form is not bound and has no `self.data`.

How do I get the existing values of the fields in a django form when going back in the browser?

(note I am using session with database backend)

Comment: The error is in the question.  The data is coming from the browser cache not the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the question. The data is coming from the browser cache not the backend.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the form use initial data.

```
data = { 'field_1': 'value'}
my_form = MyForm(initial=data)
```

Comment: Hmm thanks but that won't work. What value should that initial data take - it depends on what the user entered previously?

Comment: Yes, I presume the data that use input must be in the DB somewhere, pull that data out and set the value in the dict and pass it on as the initial data for the form

Comment: The session doesn't appear to be populating the form using initial data. So I'm still not clear how the form is being populated